# How to open a file twice using Eclipse ?

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse I have a large file and I want to watch it in different scopes at same time .

So how could I open it twice (get its 2 instance in the editor panel ) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options:

- top menu: `Window | New Editor` or
- context menu: right click on the editor tab
- joker: Ctrl+3 New Editor, this reveals the command too which you can assign a key binding in the preferences, if needed

A related trick then is to pull the editor tab of the new clone on the side or below the original one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Right-Click (over the opened file tab) -> New Editor
```